# Batch rename all files with a specific name

Tags: linux, terminal, rename

I've made a mistake somewhere when scraping (and automatically naming) images, and now in hunderds of folders they're called *...08.jpg, 09.jpg, 010.jpg, 11.jpg, 12.jpg...* The problem is the 010.jpg, which got a leading zero.

Is there a terminal command to recursively (the image sets all have their own folder) rename *all* images called 010.jpg to 10.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no bash pro, but this should do it.

```
for i in /path/to/directory/*
do
    mv ${i}/010.jpg ${i}/10.jpg
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps you find the file you're looking for in the target directory (/tmp/), and it will remove the leading zero from any file name, so it's a little more flexible than specifying to full "move to" name.

```
for i in $(find /tmp/ -name 010.jpg) ; { mv $i $(dirname $i)/$(basename $i | sed 's/^0//'); }
```

Comment: I've never used bash before, and since the first answer was a little more 'readable' for me, I used that one. Also it was a one-time problem, so it's solved now. But thanks anyway :)